# Understand multiple http request latency

Tags: api, google-chrome-devtools, httprequest, backend

I'm sending multiple http request in parallel from front-end to an api server

I noticed in chrome dev tools that the http requests are sent at the same time (  as we can see on the graph ) but not treated in parallel.

[image]

The problem is that I don't have any access to the backend so I can't give much informations except the dev tools graphics.

So I would like to know if it's possible to locate the issue ( If it's a font-end issue/ back end or navigator issue )

Comment: Definitely sounds like a back-end/API issue e.g. the requests weren't trivial or there were other clients in the queue.

Comment: I'm the only one to use this backend which is in java.